# Filtrar DataGrid WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un Datagrid con el siguiente código

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gridLogs"   ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Lo relleno mediante:

```
DataSet logs = metodoquemedevuelveundataSet();
gridLogs.DataContext = logs.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

metodoquemedevuelveundataSet me devuelve un dataset haciendo una consulta a una bd oracle.
Y relleno el datagrid con esos datos.

Me gustaría poder filtrar mediante un textbox he probado varios métodos para hacer el filtro y no lo consigo, alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Los DataGrid se pueden filtrar de varias formas pero una muy básica es esta, y debería bastar para tu problema, quedamos atentos si necesitas algo más elaborado:

Primero crea esta Propiedad:

```
public DataView SourceView
{
    get { return logs.Tables[0].DefaultView; }
}
```

Y controlando el evento TextChanged del TextBox que uses para filtrar haces la magia:

```
void TxFiltro_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SourceView.RowFilter = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim();;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        SourceView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Mañana lo pruebo y digo que tal me fue

Comment: Finalmente lo hice parecido, usé un dataview como intermediario entre el dataset y el datagrid y en el event de lo que quiero filtrar le añadi el datarow de lo que quería filtrar, lo que tu me pasaste no me servía en WPF

Comment: En serio? Pero si lo hice en WPF jajajaj aunque lo adapté de MVVM pues yo trabajo con ese patrón. Hay que implementar INotifyPropertyChanged eso si, sino no hace nada. Lo importante es que lo solucionaste.

Comment: Jaja claro, yo lo intenté tal cual, pero con lo que me pasaste y lo que encontré por internet cogí el concepto